# fancyhdr page decorations and page numbering

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, decorations

Hello there are several examples of decorative pages. Most examples work with a single page,when numbering is not necessary.

When i try to make for every page. It does not work, or i have problems with page numbers..see example below

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newcommand{\wb}[2]{\fontsize{#1}{#2}\usefont{U}{webo}{xl}{n}}
\newcommand{\wbc}[3]{\vspace*{#1}\begin{center}
    \wb{#2}{#2}#3\end{center}\vspace*{#1}}

\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\setlength{\unitlength}{1bp}%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(-36,5){\makebox(0,0)[br]{\wb{36bp}{36bp}A}}
    \end{picture}}
\rhead{\setlength{\unitlength}{1bp}%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(29,5){\makebox(0,0)[bl]{\wb{36bp}{36bp}B}}
    \end{picture}}
\lfoot{\setlength{\unitlength}{1bp}%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(-36,-3){\makebox(0,0)[tr]{\wb{36bp}{36bp}C}}
    \end{picture}}
\rfoot{\setlength{\unitlength}{1bp}%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(29,-3){\makebox(0,0)[tl]{\wb{36bp}{36bp}D}}
    \end{picture}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
 \blindtext[10]
  \wbc{2ex}{6}{IJLKIJLKIJLKIJLKIJ}

 \blindtext[3]

  \wbc{1ex}{8}{pq}


\end{document}
```

this woks fine but no page numbering becouse headers/footers are redefined

here is another example

```
% $Id: sample1.tex,v 1.3 2002/09/13 06:34:25 loreti Exp $

\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,geometry,keyval,ifthen,makeidx,multicol,mparhack,poemscol}
\usepackage{times}
\geometry{textwidth=4in,textheight=6.75in}
\makeverselinenumbers
\global\includeaccidentalstrue
\global\includetypescriptstrue
\global\redundantemendationsfalse
\stanzaatbottom{*}
\nostanzaatbottom{\relax}
%\reversemarginpar
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\newcommand{\wb}[2]{\fontsize{#1}{#2}\usefont{U}{webo}{xl}{n}}
%\newcommand{\wb}[2]{\fontsize{#1}{#2}\usefont{U}{webo}{xl}{n}}
\newcommand{\wbc}[3]{\vspace*{#1}\begin{center}
    \wb{#2}{#2}#3\end{center}\vspace*{#1}}

%\fancyhf{}
%\lhead{\setlength{\unitlength}{1bp}%
%  \begin{picture}(0,0)
%    %\put(-36,5){\makebox(0,0)[br]{\wb{36bp}{36bp} %A}}
 %   \end{picture}}
%\rhead{\setlength{\unitlength}{1bp}%
 % \begin{picture}(0,0)
 %   %\put(29,5){\makebox(0,0)[bl]{\wb{36bp}{36bp %}B}}
  %  \end{picture}}
%\lfoot{\setlength{\unitlength}{1bp}%
 % \begin{picture}(0,0)
  %  \put(-36,-3){\makebox(0,0)[tr]{\wb{36bp}{36bp}C}}
   % \end{picture}}
%\rfoot{\setlength{\unitlength}{1bp}%
 % \begin{picture}(0,0)
  %  \put(29,-3){\makebox(0,0)[tl]{\wb{36bp}{36bp}D}}
   % \end{picture}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\wb{12bp}{12bp}% 
    \begin{picture}(0,0)(59,0)
%{T}{\_}    
%{R}{\_}{O}{\_}{F}{\_}{U}   
    \put(0,0){M}
    \multiput(13,0)(13,0){30}{N}
    \put(403,0){O}
    \put(0,-533){P}
    \multiput(0,-13)(0,-13){40}{S}
    \multiput(13,-533)(13,0){30}{Q}
    \put(403,-533){R}
    \multiput(403,-13)(0,-13){40}{T}
    \end{picture}
    %\begin{picture}
    %\multiput(-18,0)(18,0){24}{N}
    %\put(450,0){M}
    %\multiput(0,-18)(0,18){34}{T}
    %\put(0,630){R}
    %\multiput(18,0)(18,630){24}{Q}
    %\multiput(0,18)(450,18){34}{S}
    %\put(450,630){P}
    %\end{picture}
%\vspace{length}
{   \normalfont \thepage}
    }
\fancyhead[RH]{\flushright  \normalfont \thepage}

%\lhead{\thepage}
%\chead{}
\rhead{}
\cfoot{\vspace{2em}\thepage} % get rid of the page number 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\begin{document}
  The King and Queen of Hearts were seated on their throne
  when they arrived, with a great crowd assembled about them
  --- all sorts of little birds and beasts, as well as the
  whole pack of cards: the Knave was standing before them,
  in chains, with a soldier on each side to guard him; and
  near the King was the White Rabbit, with a trumpet in one
  hand, and a scroll of parchment in the other.  In the very
  middle of the court was a table, with a large dish of
  tarts upon it: they looked so good, that it made Alice
  quite hungry to look at them --- ``I wish they'd get the
  trial done,'' she thought, ``and hand round the
  refreshments!''.  But there seemed to be no chance of this,
  so she began looking at everything about her to pass away
  the time.

  \wbc{2ex}{6}{IJLKIJLKIJLKIJLKIJ}

  Alice had never been in a court of justice before, but she
  had read about them in books, and she was quite pleased to
  find that she knew the name of nearly everything there.
  ``That's the judge,'' she said to herself, ``because of his
  great wig.''.

  The judge, by the way, was the King, and as he wore his
  crown over the wig, (look at the frontispiece if you want
  to see how he did it,) he did not look at all comfortable,
  and it was certainly not becoming.

  \wbc{1ex}{8}{pq}

  ``And that's the jury-box,'' thought Alice, ``and those
  twelve creatures,'' (she was obliged to say ``creatures,''
  you see, because some of them were animals, and some were
  birds) ``I suppose they are the jurors.''.  She said this
  last word two or three times over to herself being rather
  proud of it: for she thought, and rightly too, that very
  few little girls of her age knew the meaning of it at all.
  However, ``jurymen'' would have done just as well.

  \wbc{1ex}{10}{ced}

  The twelve jurors were all writing very busily on slates.
  ``What are they doing?'' Alice whispered to the Gryphon.
  ``They can't have anything to put down yet, before the
  trial's begun.''.

  ``They're putting down their names,'' the Gryphon
  whispered in reply, ``for fear they should forget them
  before the end of the trial.''.

  ``Stupid things!'' Alice began in a loud indignant voice,
  but she stopped herself hastily, for the White Rabbit
  cried out, ``Silence in the court!''; and the King put on
  his spectacles and looked anxiously round, to make out who
  was talking.
\end{document}

% $Id: sample1.tex,v 1.3 2002/09/13 06:34:25 loreti Exp $
```

1. Is there a way to make page numbering to left/right and not in center?
2. I mostly use memoir class and How do same thing with memoir class without fancyhdr?

Comment: (1) It's not really clear what you're after, since you (obviously) include `\thepage` as part of your header definition. So, just put `\thepage` where you want it to display and it will go there. (2) This seems contradicting to (1), which uses [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr). Seems like these should be two separate questions...

Comment: \thepage in footer center works fine...but not left/right sides. It is always on left or on right side of the page, not like in usual way...that's why i put it in center...

Comment: You can see '1' and '2' inside of ornament they are on same side

Comment: You still have `\thepage` as part of your definition of `\lhead`, so of course it will be inside the "ornament" on the same (left) side...

Comment: Where exactly do you want the page number to appear?

Comment: You can say, e.g. `\fancyhf[ROH,LEH]{\thepage}` to get the page number to alternate between left and right in a two-sided document. Is that what you mean? Like others, I'm confused by your question (or questions).

Comment: yes but it does not nelp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `memoir`, you first declare your page style using

```
\makepagestyle{<name>}
```

where  is the name you chose for your page style. Then you define your headers/footers using

```
\makeevenhead{<name>}{<left>}{<center>}{<right>}
\makeoddhead{<name>}{<left>}{<center>}{<right>}
\makeevenfoot{<name>}{<left>}{<center>}{<right>}
\makeoddfoot{<name>}{<left>}{<center>}{<right>}
```

An example with your first style:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\wb}[2]{\fontsize{#1}{#2}\usefont{U}{webo}{xl}{n}}
\newcommand{\wbc}[3]{\vspace*{#1}\begin{center}
    \wb{#2}{#2}#3\end{center}\vspace*{#1}}

\makepagestyle{myps}
\makeevenhead{myps}
  {\setlength{\unitlength}{1bp}%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(-36,5){\makebox(0,0)[br]{\wb{36bp}{36bp}A}}
    \end{picture}
  }
  {}
  {\setlength{\unitlength}{1bp}%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(29,5){\makebox(0,0)[bl]{\wb{36bp}{36bp}B}}
    \end{picture}
  }
\makeoddhead{myps}
  {\setlength{\unitlength}{1bp}%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(-36,5){\makebox(0,0)[br]{\wb{36bp}{36bp}A}}
    \end{picture}%
  }
  {}
  {\setlength{\unitlength}{1bp}%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(29,5){\makebox(0,0)[bl]{\wb{36bp}{36bp}B}}
    \end{picture}%
  }
\makeevenfoot{myps}
  {\setlength{\unitlength}{1bp}%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(-36,-3){\makebox(0,0)[tr]{\wb{36bp}{36bp}C}}
    \end{picture}%
  }
  {}
  {\setlength{\unitlength}{1bp}%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(29,-3){\makebox(0,0)[tl]{\wb{36bp}{36bp}D}}
    \end{picture}%
  }
\makeoddfoot{myps}
  {\setlength{\unitlength}{1bp}%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(-36,-3){\makebox(0,0)[tr]{\wb{36bp}{36bp}C}}
    \end{picture}%
  }
  {}
  {\setlength{\unitlength}{1bp}%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(29,-3){\makebox(0,0)[tl]{\wb{36bp}{36bp}D}}
    \end{picture}%
  }

\pagestyle{myps}

\begin{document}
 \blindtext[10]
  \wbc{2ex}{6}{IJLKIJLKIJLKIJLKIJ}

 \blindtext[3]

  \wbc{1ex}{8}{pq}


\end{document}
```

[image]

And, with the second style (notice that `\makeevenfoot`, `\makeoddfoot` were used to place the page numbers below the frame):

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{geometry,keyval,ifthen,makeidx,multicol,mparhack}
\usepackage{times}
\geometry{textwidth=4in,textheight=6.75in}

\newcommand{\wb}[2]{\fontsize{#1}{#2}\usefont{U}{webo}{xl}{n}}
%\newcommand{\wb}[2]{\fontsize{#1}{#2}\usefont{U}{webo}{xl}{n}}
\newcommand{\wbc}[3]{\vspace*{#1}\begin{center}
    \wb{#2}{#2}#3\end{center}\vspace*{#1}}

%\fancyhf{}
%\lhead{\setlength{\unitlength}{1bp}%
%  \begin{picture}(0,0)
%    %\put(-36,5){\makebox(0,0)[br]{\wb{36bp}{36bp} %A}}
 %   \end{picture}}
%\rhead{\setlength{\unitlength}{1bp}%
 % \begin{picture}(0,0)
 %   %\put(29,5){\makebox(0,0)[bl]{\wb{36bp}{36bp %}B}}
  %  \end{picture}}
%\lfoot{\setlength{\unitlength}{1bp}%
 % \begin{picture}(0,0)
  %  \put(-36,-3){\makebox(0,0)[tr]{\wb{36bp}{36bp}C}}
   % \end{picture}}
%\rfoot{\setlength{\unitlength}{1bp}%
 % \begin{picture}(0,0)
  %  \put(29,-3){\makebox(0,0)[tl]{\wb{36bp}{36bp}D}}
   % \end{picture}}

\makepagestyle{mypsii}
\makeevenhead{mypsii}
  {\wb{12bp}{12bp}% 
    \begin{picture}(0,0)(59,0)
%{T}{\_}    
%{R}{\_}{O}{\_}{F}{\_}{U}   
    \put(0,0){M}
    \multiput(13,0)(13,0){30}{N}
    \put(403,0){O}
    \put(0,-533){P}
    \multiput(0,-13)(0,-13){40}{S}
    \multiput(13,-533)(13,0){30}{Q}
    \put(403,-533){R}
    \multiput(403,-13)(0,-13){40}{T}
    \end{picture}%
  }
  {}
  {}
\makeoddhead{mypsii}
  {\wb{12bp}{12bp}% 
    \begin{picture}(0,0)(59,0)
%{T}{\_}    
%{R}{\_}{O}{\_}{F}{\_}{U}   
    \put(0,0){M}
    \multiput(13,0)(13,0){30}{N}
    \put(403,0){O}
    \put(0,-533){P}
    \multiput(0,-13)(0,-13){40}{S}
    \multiput(13,-533)(13,0){30}{Q}
    \put(403,-533){R}
    \multiput(403,-13)(0,-13){40}{T}
    \end{picture}%
  }
  {}
  {}
\makeevenfoot{mypsii}
  {\put(360,-3){\makebox(0,0)[tr]{\normalfont \thepage}}}
  {}
  {}
\makeoddfoot{mypsii}
  {\put(-55,-3){\makebox(0,0)[tr]{\normalfont \thepage}}}
  {}
  {}

\pagestyle{mypsii}

\begin{document}
  The King and Queen of Hearts were seated on their throne
  when they arrived, with a great crowd assembled about them
  --- all sorts of little birds and beasts, as well as the
  whole pack of cards: the Knave was standing before them,
  in chains, with a soldier on each side to guard him; and
  near the King was the White Rabbit, with a trumpet in one
  hand, and a scroll of parchment in the other.  In the very
  middle of the court was a table, with a large dish of
  tarts upon it: they looked so good, that it made Alice
  quite hungry to look at them --- ``I wish they'd get the
  trial done,'' she thought, ``and hand round the
  refreshments!''.  But there seemed to be no chance of this,
  so she began looking at everything about her to pass away
  the time.

  \wbc{2ex}{6}{IJLKIJLKIJLKIJLKIJ}

  Alice had never been in a court of justice before, but she
  had read about them in books, and she was quite pleased to
  find that she knew the name of nearly everything there.
  ``That's the judge,'' she said to herself, ``because of his
  great wig.''.

  The judge, by the way, was the King, and as he wore his
  crown over the wig, (look at the frontispiece if you want
  to see how he did it,) he did not look at all comfortable,
  and it was certainly not becoming.

  \wbc{1ex}{8}{pq}

  ``And that's the jury-box,'' thought Alice, ``and those
  twelve creatures,'' (she was obliged to say ``creatures,''
  you see, because some of them were animals, and some were
  birds) ``I suppose they are the jurors.''.  She said this
  last word two or three times over to herself being rather
  proud of it: for she thought, and rightly too, that very
  few little girls of her age knew the meaning of it at all.
  However, ``jurymen'' would have done just as well.

  \wbc{1ex}{10}{ced}

  The twelve jurors were all writing very busily on slates.
  ``What are they doing?'' Alice whispered to the Gryphon.
  ``They can't have anything to put down yet, before the
  trial's begun.''.

  ``They're putting down their names,'' the Gryphon
  whispered in reply, ``for fear they should forget them
  before the end of the trial.''.

  ``Stupid things!'' Alice began in a loud indignant voice,
  but she stopped herself hastily, for the White Rabbit
  cried out, ``Silence in the court!''; and the King put on
  his spectacles and looked anxiously round, to make out who
  was talking.
\end{document}
```

[image]

A zoomed image of the bottom of the first page, showing the page number:

[image]

Using `fancyhdr` the idea is the same, but using the package interface:

```
\fancyfoot[LO]{<code for page number>}
\fancyfoot[RE]{<code for page number>}
```

or

```
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{<code for page number>}
```

if the code is similar.

An example using fancyhdr and the second style:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,geometry,keyval,ifthen,makeidx,multicol,mparhack,poemscol}
\usepackage{times}
\geometry{textwidth=4in,textheight=6.75in}
\makeverselinenumbers
\global\includeaccidentalstrue
\global\includetypescriptstrue
\global\redundantemendationsfalse
\stanzaatbottom{*}
\nostanzaatbottom{\relax}
%\reversemarginpar

\setlength\headheight{12.05pt}

\newcommand{\wb}[2]{\fontsize{#1}{#2}\usefont{U}{webo}{xl}{n}}
%\newcommand{\wb}[2]{\fontsize{#1}{#2}\usefont{U}{webo}{xl}{n}}
\newcommand{\wbc}[3]{\vspace*{#1}\begin{center}
    \wb{#2}{#2}#3\end{center}\vspace*{#1}}

%\fancyhf{}
%\lhead{\setlength{\unitlength}{1bp}%
%  \begin{picture}(0,0)
%    %\put(-36,5){\makebox(0,0)[br]{\wb{36bp}{36bp} %A}}
 %   \end{picture}}
%\rhead{\setlength{\unitlength}{1bp}%
 % \begin{picture}(0,0)
 %   %\put(29,5){\makebox(0,0)[bl]{\wb{36bp}{36bp %}B}}
  %  \end{picture}}
%\lfoot{\setlength{\unitlength}{1bp}%
 % \begin{picture}(0,0)
  %  \put(-36,-3){\makebox(0,0)[tr]{\wb{36bp}{36bp}C}}
   % \end{picture}}
%\rfoot{\setlength{\unitlength}{1bp}%
 % \begin{picture}(0,0)
  %  \put(29,-3){\makebox(0,0)[tl]{\wb{36bp}{36bp}D}}
   % \end{picture}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\wb{12bp}{12bp}% 
    \begin{picture}(0,0)(59,0)
%{T}{\_}    
%{R}{\_}{O}{\_}{F}{\_}{U}   
    \put(0,0){M}
    \multiput(13,0)(13,0){30}{N}
    \put(403,0){O}
    \put(0,-533){P}
    \multiput(0,-13)(0,-13){40}{S}
    \multiput(13,-533)(13,0){30}{Q}
    \put(403,-533){R}
    \multiput(403,-13)(0,-13){40}{T}
    \end{picture}
    %\begin{picture}
    %\multiput(-18,0)(18,0){24}{N}
    %\put(450,0){M}
    %\multiput(0,-18)(0,18){34}{T}
    %\put(0,630){R}
    %\multiput(18,0)(18,630){24}{Q}
    %\multiput(0,18)(450,18){34}{S}
    %\put(450,630){P}
    %\end{picture}
%\vspace{length}
}
\fancyfoot[LO]{%
  \leavevmode
  \put(359,-3){\makebox(0,0)[tr]{\normalfont\thepage}}
}
\fancyfoot[RE]{%
  \leavevmode  
  \put(-344,-3){\makebox(0,0)[tr]{\normalfont\thepage}}
}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
  The King and Queen of Hearts were seated on their throne
  when they arrived, with a great crowd assembled about them
  --- all sorts of little birds and beasts, as well as the
  whole pack of cards: the Knave was standing before them,
  in chains, with a soldier on each side to guard him; and
  near the King was the White Rabbit, with a trumpet in one
  hand, and a scroll of parchment in the other.  In the very
  middle of the court was a table, with a large dish of
  tarts upon it: they looked so good, that it made Alice
  quite hungry to look at them --- ``I wish they'd get the
  trial done,'' she thought, ``and hand round the
  refreshments!''.  But there seemed to be no chance of this,
  so she began looking at everything about her to pass away
  the time.

  \wbc{2ex}{6}{IJLKIJLKIJLKIJLKIJ}

  Alice had never been in a court of justice before, but she
  had read about them in books, and she was quite pleased to
  find that she knew the name of nearly everything there.
  ``That's the judge,'' she said to herself, ``because of his
  great wig.''.

  The judge, by the way, was the King, and as he wore his
  crown over the wig, (look at the frontispiece if you want
  to see how he did it,) he did not look at all comfortable,
  and it was certainly not becoming.

  \wbc{1ex}{8}{pq}

  ``And that's the jury-box,'' thought Alice, ``and those
  twelve creatures,'' (she was obliged to say ``creatures,''
  you see, because some of them were animals, and some were
  birds) ``I suppose they are the jurors.''.  She said this
  last word two or three times over to herself being rather
  proud of it: for she thought, and rightly too, that very
  few little girls of her age knew the meaning of it at all.
  However, ``jurymen'' would have done just as well.

  \wbc{1ex}{10}{ced}

  The twelve jurors were all writing very busily on slates.
  ``What are they doing?'' Alice whispered to the Gryphon.
  ``They can't have anything to put down yet, before the
  trial's begun.''.

  ``They're putting down their names,'' the Gryphon
  whispered in reply, ``for fear they should forget them
  before the end of the trial.''.

  ``Stupid things!'' Alice began in a loud indignant voice,
  but she stopped herself hastily, for the White Rabbit
  cried out, ``Silence in the court!''; and the King put on
  his spectacles and looked anxiously round, to make out who
  was talking.
\end{document}

  ``Stupid things!'' Alice began in a loud indignant voice,
  but she stopped herself hastily, for the White Rabbit
  cried out, ``Silence in the court!''; and the King put on
  his spectacles and looked anxiously round, to make out who
  was talking.
\end{document}
```

An image of the bottom of the first page:

[image]

Feel free to change the settings according to your needs.

Comment: nice, but there are not a page numbers...thats what i mean. numbers dissapear or one can put only in center.

Comment: @ShakroTrubeckoi I asked you in a comment where exactly do you want the page numbers.

Comment: I added page numbering in your code . make evenfoot: \put(360,-3){\makebox(0,0)[tr]{\normalfont \thepage}} and make addfoot:  \put(-36,-3){\makebox(0,0)[tr]{\normalfont \thepage}}...works fine...can be better solution?

Comment: @ShakroTrubeckoi yes, that's what you need.

Comment: and created \makeevenfoot{mypsii}
    {   \put(340,25){\makebox(0,0)[tr]{\normalfont \thepage}} 
    }
    {}
    {} ..it seems with memoir solution is simpler ? thanks a lot :)

Comment: @ShakroTrubeckoi please see my updated answer for an example with page numbers, and some comment about how to do the same with `fancyhdr`.

Comment: @ShakroTrubeckoi You're welcome!