# borders around page using pgfornament

Tags: tikz-pgf

EDITED:
I know this example [ornaments in pgfornament to be at the corners at every page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159597/ornaments-in-pgfornament-to-be-at-the-corners-at-every-page)

but how to add ornament in horizontal and vertical/top bottom /?
I need this only on titlepage of memoir class.

Here is a code from answers i have found/including answer on this page/:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[paper=a4paper, verbose, centering]{geometry}
    \usepackage{pgfornament}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \newcommand{\pageborders}[3]{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
          \node[shift={(1cm,-1cm)},anchor=north west](CNW)
      at (current page.north west) 
      {\pgfornament[width=1.75cm]{#1}};
      \node[shift={(-1cm,-1cm)},anchor=north east](CNE)
      at (current page.north east) 
      {\pgfornament[width=1.75cm,symmetry=v]{#1}};
      \node[shift={(1cm,1cm)},anchor=south west](CSW)
      at (current page.south west) {\pgfornament[width=1.75cm,symmetry=h]{#1}};
      \node[shift={(-1cm,1cm)},anchor=south east](CSE)
      at (current page.south east) 
      {\pgfornament[width=1.75cm,symmetry=c]{#1}};
      \pgfornamenthline{CNW}{CNE}{north}{#2}
      \pgfornamenthline{CSW}{CSE}{south}{#2}
      \pgfornamentvline{CNW}{CSW}{west}{#3}
      \pgfornamentvline{CNE}{CSE}{east}{#3}
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    }

    \title{Title}
    \author{Author}
    \date{}

    \usepackage{kantlipsum,titling}% for demo only

    \begin{document}

    \maketitle\pageborders{61}{84}{87}\thispagestyle{empty}
    \clearpage%

    \end{document}
```

Questions:

1. How to adjust ornaments in 'ornamentlines' (like node shifts for corners) to make ornaments link together?
2. how to use multiple ornaments on vertical/horizontal lines?/lets say same ornament multiple times linked together from corner to
   corner
3. how to change symmetry of ornament, which is used in 'ornamentlines'
4. how to scale ornaments used in 'ornamentlines'/let say ornament used in vertical border scaled by width and ornament used in
   horizontal scaled by height/
   [image]

and here is a webomint's example..sorry i can not find source file right now:
[image]

related question using webomints is here
[fancyhdr page decorations and page numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159210/fancyhdr-page-decorations-and-page-numbering)

Comment: As it is now, your question is very vague. In order to help you, we'd need to see some code and perhaps a screenshot explaining what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Also, I just realised that the question contradicts the description - vertical \neq horizontal.

Comment: The thing is, some ornaments are designed to fit together. Others are not really. It isn't just a question of scaling. The directions in which the lines are going means that the corner ornaments you've chosen won't 'fit' properly with the vertical and horizontal ornaments. Is there any particular reason you want to use `pgfornmanents` specifically? There are plenty of decorations which are designed for this so it seems a little strange to insist on using ones which are not. The ornaments you've chosen in your example seem clearly not to complement each other stylistically in any case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Jubobs says, your question is extremely vague. I'm not sure what you mean by horizontally exactly - horizontally at the top? In the centre? Top and bottom? At the edges? In the middle? Etc.

Still, you should be able to adapt the following:

[image: Sampler with ornaments]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper, verbose, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfornament}

\newcommand{\corner}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[anchor=north west] at (current page.north west){%
      \pgfornament[width=2cm]{#1}};
    \node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east){%
      \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=v]{#1}};
    \node[anchor=south west] at (current page.south west){%
      \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=h]{#1}};
    \node[anchor=south east] at (current page.south east){%
      \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=c]{#1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand{\cornerplus}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[anchor=north west] at (current page.north west){%
      \pgfornament[width=2cm]{#1}};
    \node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east){%
      \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=v]{#1}};
    \node[anchor=south west] at (current page.south west){%
      \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=h]{#1}};
    \node[anchor=south east] at (current page.south east){%
      \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=c]{#1}};
    \node[anchor=north] at (current page.north){%
      \pgfornament[width=6.5cm,symmetry=h]{#2}};
    \node[anchor=south] at (current page.south){%
      \pgfornament[width=6.5cm]{#2}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand{\pt}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[anchor=north] at (current page.north){%
      \pgfornament[symmetry=h]{#1}};
    \node[anchor=south] at (current page.south){%
      \pgfornament[symmetry=h]{#1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{}

\usepackage{kantlipsum,titling}% for demo only

\begin{document}
\maketitle\corner{31}\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage%
\maketitle\cornerplus{61}{85}\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage%
\maketitle\cornerplus{63}{85}\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage%
\maketitle\pt{84}\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage%
\maketitle\pt{71}\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage%
\maketitle\pt{87}\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage%
\end{document}
```

## Update

Although `pgfornaments` does not really seem to feature decorations which are designed to 'fit together' or link in the way some decorative fonts do, for example, if you select ornaments carefully, you can create this sort of effect. I found that the best choices were squarish ornaments because you can easily slot them into `nodes` on `chains` in a `tikzpicture`. For example:

[image: Ornamental frames using repeated ornaments]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper, verbose, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{}

\usepackage{titling}% for demo only

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, start chain, node distance=-2mm]
    \node (nworn) [shift={(5mm,-5mm)}, anchor=north west, on chain ] at (current page.north west) {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{7}};
    \foreach \i in {1,...,17}
      \node [on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{7}};
    \node (neorn) [on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{7}};
    \foreach \i in {1,...,25}
      \node [continue chain=going below, on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{7}};
    \node (seorn) [on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{7}};
    \foreach \i in {1,...,17}
      \node [continue chain=going left, on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{7}};
    \node (sworn) [on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{7}};
    \foreach \i in {1,...,25}
      \node [continue chain=going above, on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{7}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage

\maketitle
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, start chain, node distance=-2mm]
    \node (nworn) [shift={(10mm,-10mm)}, anchor=north west, on chain ] at (current page.north west){\pgfornament[width=10mm]{61}};
    \foreach \i in {1,...,8}
      {\node [on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{62}};
      \node [on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{61}};}
    \node (neorn) [on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{62}};
    \foreach \i in {1,...,12}
      {\node [continue chain=going below, on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm,symmetry=h]{62}};
      \node [continue chain=going below, on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{62}};}
    \node (seorn) [on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm,symmetry=h]{62}};
    \foreach \i in {1,...,8}
      {\node [continue chain=going left, on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm,symmetry=h]{61}};
      \node [continue chain=going left, on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm,symmetry=h]{62}};}
    \node (sworn) [on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm,symmetry=h]{61}};
    \foreach \i in {1,...,12}
      {\node [continue chain=going above, on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{61}};
      \node [continue chain=going above, on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm,symmetry=h]{61}};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks... Agree. question was not clear. Original post in link is about ornaments on corners on page. There is a picture that author was not interesting about other sides (vertical and horizontal).  my question is how to do decorations around page using pgfornaments. I have done same using webomint font...I need closedpath decoration not like : corners, top bottom, left side, right side...in an example shown in the link pgf ornaments are "scaled"...how To do same in Y direction on page?

Comment: @ShakroTrubeckoi Could you maybe post an example using webomint? You can edit your original question to do this. I think that would make it a lot clearer exactly what you are trying to do. Once it is clearer, the question can be reopened to make sure you get useful answers.

Comment: question edited....

Comment: @ShakroTrubeckoi See my edited answer and my comments on your updated question.

Comment: can "ON HOLD" be removed?

Comment: @ShakroTrubeckoi I started the process to request this by voting to 'reopen' it but so far I seem to be the only voter. Maybe flag the question for moderator attention? Questions are meant to get reopened if they get clarified but I don't know what more to do besides voting myself to start the process. Sorry.