# Elegant restaurant menu with Latex

Tags: templates, pgfornament

**How can I produce a restaurant menu with Latex that (1) is similar to this one in the picture (pic from the [website of classy menus](https://www.cardsandpockets.com/classy-menu.aspx))** [image]

**and (2) that has this frame around (frame's code [by "cfr" in "borders around page using pgfornament"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168331/borders-around-page-using-pgfornament)) ?**

[image]

**This is the code for the external frame with ornaments:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper, verbose, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfornament}

\newcommand{\corner}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[anchor=north west] at (current page.north west){%
      \pgfornament[width=2cm]{#1}};
    \node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east){%
      \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=v]{#1}};
    \node[anchor=south west] at (current page.south west){%
      \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=h]{#1}};
    \node[anchor=south east] at (current page.south east){%
      \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=c]{#1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand{\cornerplus}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[anchor=north west] at (current page.north west){%
      \pgfornament[width=2cm]{#1}};
    \node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east){%
      \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=v]{#1}};
    \node[anchor=south west] at (current page.south west){%
      \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=h]{#1}};
    \node[anchor=south east] at (current page.south east){%
      \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=c]{#1}};
    \node[anchor=north] at (current page.north){%
      \pgfornament[width=6.5cm,symmetry=h]{#2}};
    \node[anchor=south] at (current page.south){%
      \pgfornament[width=6.5cm]{#2}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand{\pt}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[anchor=north] at (current page.north){%
      \pgfornament[symmetry=h]{#1}};
    \node[anchor=south] at (current page.south){%
      \pgfornament[symmetry=h]{#1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\usepackage{kantlipsum,titling}% for demo only

\begin{document}

\maketitle\cornerplus{61}{85}\thispagestyle{empty}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why a negative vote for my question ? What is the reason?

Comment: This site doesn't work well with "please do this for me".  You've shown us someone else's code for the frame, but haven't made even a basic attempt at putting the content of your menu inside of that frame.  As a result, you've gotten an answer that doesn't go too far toward the first image that you were aiming for.

Comment: Thanks @Teepeemm ! Is what you said, i.e. "This site doesn't work well with "please do this for me"", a sort of rule written somewhere in some policy or regulations of StackExchange ? Or is it just a sort of unwritten rule that all the users of StackExchange are supposed to know in advance before asking any question ? In addition, just for information, for some people, writing such a comment ("This site doesn't work well with "please do this for me""), can sound a bit conceited, and might draw the attention of moderators. I will consider this rule in the next posts/questions, if any. Regards

Comment: Voting is done by individuals and if there is no comment the reason of a down voted is unknown. As @Teepeemm said it could be one of them who don't like "do it for me question"., see e.g. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8311/dealing-with-just-do-it-for-me-questions. But it could also be that someone didn't like the menu, or the color of your avatar,  or simply clicked at random on a bad day.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, good to know that people can downvote a question for any reason.... I did not know... thanks for letting me know! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am very impressed by your code for the page frame.

Your problem seems to be how to layout the menu items. The following might give an indication of how to do that.

```
% menuprob.tex  SE 643006

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper, verbose, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfornament}

\newcommand{\corner}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[anchor=north west] at (current page.north west){%
      \pgfornament[width=2cm]{#1}};
    \node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east){%
      \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=v]{#1}};
    \node[anchor=south west] at (current page.south west){%
      \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=h]{#1}};
    \node[anchor=south east] at (current page.south east){%
      \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=c]{#1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand{\cornerplus}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[anchor=north west] at (current page.north west){%
      \pgfornament[width=2cm]{#1}};
    \node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east){%
      \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=v]{#1}};
    \node[anchor=south west] at (current page.south west){%
      \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=h]{#1}};
    \node[anchor=south east] at (current page.south east){%
      \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=c]{#1}};
    \node[anchor=north] at (current page.north){%
      \pgfornament[width=6.5cm,symmetry=h]{#2}};
    \node[anchor=south] at (current page.south){%
      \pgfornament[width=6.5cm]{#2}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand{\pt}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[anchor=north] at (current page.north){%
      \pgfornament[symmetry=h]{#1}};
    \node[anchor=south] at (current page.south){%
      \pgfornament[symmetry=h]{#1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\usepackage{kantlipsum,titling}% for demo only

\begin{document}

\maketitle\cornerplus{61}{85}\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
  {\huge \textbf{MENU}}

  Please inform your server \ldots

\end{center}

\begin{center}
  \textbf{Hors d'oevres}

  \textsc{assorted cheeses \& artisan crackers}

  \end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As far as you are concerned you have to specify the fonts and sizes for the relevant items in the menu. Sorry, I can't help with that.

Comment: It looks like the page frame is #2 from the page OP linked to, so I don't know that they've done all that much to be impressed about.

Comment: Great @PeterWilson, thank you very much!!! This is an amazing answer, thanks!!

Comment: @Teepeemm I assumed that the OP had created the framing code, not copied it from elsewhere. I have not compared the framing code from the OP's linked page with the code the OP presented. Are they the same? If the code was just copied I'm not impressed by the OP but impressed by whoever created it in the first place.

Comment: Hello, As I wrote in my original question, the code I presented there is not mine. Indeed I wrote "....and (2) that has this frame around (frame's code by "cfr" in "borders around page using pgfornament") ?", i.e. the frame's code was created by user "cfr", in the thread there linked... :-)