# Create page border using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to create the page border like the image in the attachment but I don't know how to do that? Please help me and thank you.[image]

Comment: Rather than constructing them within `tikz`, this answer of mine, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208977/how-do-i-add-beautiful-borders-to-the-title-page/209017#209017, shows how to employ ready-made borders that you may find on the internet.

Comment: Thank for your help but I have another question is how I scale image to fit with my content (with size of image is the best for content)?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159210/fancyhdr-page-decorations-and-page-numbering, http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159216/1952, http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159603/1952, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/801/1952

Answer (score 13):

If the given border is only an example to show what you want to do you could use the package [`pgfornament`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfornament).

Using [scrlayer-scrpage](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrlayer-scrpage) the border could be added to one or more layer page styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[%
  margin=4cm
  %,showframe% to show the page layout
]{geometry}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}

\newcommand\om{5mm}% ornament margin
\newcommand\ow{5cm}% ornament width
\newcommand\ols{5.5mm}% ornament line shift
\newcommand\on{63}% ornament number
\colorlet{bordercolor}{purple}
\tikzset{
ol/.style={line width=1mm,dotted}% style for the lines
}

% define the border and save it in a box
\newsavebox\border
\sbox\border{%
  \tikz[color=bordercolor]{
    \useasboundingbox(0,0)rectangle(\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
    \foreach[count=\i]\a/\p/\s in {%
      north west/{\om,-\om}/none,
      north east/{{\paperwidth-\om},-\om}/v,
      south east/{{\paperwidth-\om},{-\paperheight+\om}}/c,%
      south west/{\om,{-\paperheight+\om}}/h%
      }\node[anchor=\a](n\i) at (\p){\pgfornament[width=\ow,symmetry=\s]{\on}};
    \begin{scope}[ol]
      \draw([yshift=-\ols]n1.north east)--([yshift=-\ols]n2.north west);
      \draw([xshift=-\ols]n2.south east)--([xshift=-\ols]n3.north east);
      \draw([yshift=\ols]n3.south west)--([yshift=\ols]n4.south east);
      \draw([xshift=\ols]n4.north west)--([xshift=\ols]n1.south west);
    \end{scope}
  }%
}

\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot*{\pagemark}

% define a switch to enable and disable the border
\newif\ifBorder
% define a new layer
\DeclareNewLayer[{%
    background,
    page,
    contents={\ifBorder\usebox\border\fi}
  }]{border.bg}
% add the border layer to all layer page styles (scrheadings, plain, empty, ...) ...
\AddLayersAtBeginOfPageStyle{@everystyle@}{border.bg}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\Bordertrue% enable the border
\Blindtext[10]
\clearpage
\Borderfalse% disable the border
\Blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `scrlayer-scrpage` it is also possible to disable the border on selected page styles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[%
  margin=4cm
  %,showframe% to show the page layout
]{geometry}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}

\newcommand\om{5mm}% ornament margin
\newcommand\ow{5cm}% ornament width
\newcommand\ols{5.5mm}% ornament line shift
\newcommand\on{63}% ornament number
\colorlet{bordercolor}{purple}
\tikzset{
ol/.style={line width=1mm,dotted}% style for the lines
}

% define the border and save it in a box
\newsavebox\border
\sbox\border{%
  \tikz[color=bordercolor]{
    \useasboundingbox(0,0)rectangle(\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
    \foreach[count=\i]\a/\p/\s in {%
      north west/{\om,-\om}/none,
      north east/{{\paperwidth-\om},-\om}/v,
      south east/{{\paperwidth-\om},{-\paperheight+\om}}/c,%
      south west/{\om,{-\paperheight+\om}}/h%
      }\node[anchor=\a](n\i) at (\p){\pgfornament[width=\ow,symmetry=\s]{\on}};
    \begin{scope}[ol]
      \draw([yshift=-\ols]n1.north east)--([yshift=-\ols]n2.north west);
      \draw([xshift=-\ols]n2.south east)--([xshift=-\ols]n3.north east);
      \draw([yshift=\ols]n3.south west)--([yshift=\ols]n4.south east);
      \draw([xshift=\ols]n4.north west)--([xshift=\ols]n1.south west);
    \end{scope}
  }%
}

\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\color{blue!50!green!80!black}\large}
\chead*{The current page style is \toplevelpagestyle{} \ifstr{\toplevelpagestyle}{\currentpagestyle}{}{as alias for \currentpagestyle}.}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}

% define a switch to enable and disable the border
\newif\ifBorder
% define a new layer
\DeclareNewLayer[{%
    background,
    page,
    contents={\ifBorder\usebox\border\fi}
  }]{border.bg}
% add the border layer to all layer page styles (scrheadings, plain, empty, ...) ...
\AddLayersAtBeginOfPageStyle{@everystyle@}{border.bg}
% but no border on empty pages 
\AddToLayerPageStyleOptions{empty}{oninit=\Borderfalse}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\Bordertrue
\Blindtext
\clearpage
\pagestyle{empty}
\Blindtext[10]
\clearpage
\pagestyle{plain}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

The pagestyle on page 1 is `scrheadings` and on page 4 `plain` both with border. But pages 2 and 3 use pagestyle empty and there is no border because of

```
\AddToLayerPageStyleOptions{empty}{oninit=\Borderfalse}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, I'm very glad to thank esdd to help me another way to create nice border page, thank esdd.

Comment: @richard Thanks for the hint. I have updated my answer, because package `pgfornament` is on CTAN and also part of MiKTeX and TL.

Answer (score 10):

Saving your border as `ZmI9O.jpg`, and employing my answer referenced in my comment, I only had to adjust the filename, paper (aspect), scale, and the offset to create a letter using your border.

Upon EDIT, I used the `geometry` package to show how to set the margin to fit the border, and changed the hook from "Thispage" to "Everypage", so that the border would continue on subsequent pages.

```
\documentclass[letter]{article}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
% THESE ARE LaTeX DEFAULTS; CAN CHANGE IF NEEDED.
\def\PageTopMargin{1in}
\def\PageLeftMargin{1in}
\newcommand\atxy[3]{%
 \AddEverypageHook{\smash{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\PageLeftMargin-\hoffset+#1\relax}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\PageTopMargin+\voffset-#2\relax}{#3}}}}
% VERIFIED THAT SETTING \hoffset AND \voffset DO NOT BREAK SOLUTION.
%\hoffset=0.4in
%\voffset=0.2in
\begin{document}
\atxy{-1.65in}{11.4in}{\includegraphics[scale=1.42]{ZmI9O}}
\lipsum[1-7]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have followed your example, but the image of page border seem slightly blurred image, how can I  resolve it? Here the image of this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8J0RK.png

Comment: @datanhlg It is blurred because the original shown in your question is likewise blurred (and I copied that for use).  Presumably, you have access to a high-resolution version of it somewhere, and you should use that version.  Of course, when you do, you will likely have to adjust the `scale=` value and the `\atxy` coordinates.

Comment: Oh, thank for your help, it's very useful to me because I'm just using LaTex, thank again Steven B. Segletes.

Comment: @datanhlg If you are using "plain" LaTeX, the image that comprises the border will have to be an encapsulated postscript (EPS) file.  If you are using pdflatex or similar, the border image can be a PDF, JPG, PNG, etc (many formats *except* EPS).  Best wishes!

Comment: Best wishes to you too. Thank Steven B. Segletes.